# Utilities for creating a lock hierarchy?

Tags: c++

According to the answers found in [Threads and simple Dead lock cure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892619/threads-and-simple-dead-lock-cure) and also [Herb Sutter](http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=204801163&siteSectionName=) the key to avoiding deadlock is by using lock hierarchies.

Are there any good C++ libraries that provide support for this? I can't find any in Boost or Poco.

Ideally it would be a system that allows one to define the hierarchy at compile-time. Perhaps it would look like this:

```
template<class LowerLevelMutex>
class RankedMutex { ... };

class BottomMutex { ... };

typedef RankedMutex<BottomMutex> L1Mutex;
typedef RankedMutex<L1Mutex> L2Mutex;
typedef RankedMutex<L2Mutex> L3Mutex;
// ...
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no one key to avoiding deadlock and no simple bandage when you've got it. Far better to avoid it in the design process. What is your particular case?

Comment: @Platinum Azure: I'm looking for solutions for deadlock problems in an old and large codebase.

Comment: I've got nothing then, sorry. :-(

Comment: Did you check `boost::recursive_mutex` ?

Comment: @Alexandre recursive_mutex only prevents a self-deadlock of one thread locking the same mutex twice.  It does nothing to solve two threads locking two mutexes in opposite order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, lock hierarchies can effectively prevent deadlocks; of course whether you can actually define a hierarchy for your program (especially, in the presence of plugins) is another matter entirely.

The basic blocks are simple:

- Each mutex should have a level (either determined at compile-time or run-time)
- Each thread should only ever acquire mutex in ascending or descending level (decide once)

*I hope I can do the idea justice, please consider the example implementation below a sketch; it has never been compiled/tested.*

A basic mutex:

```
template <typename Mutex, size_t Level>
class HierarchicalMutex {
public:
    friend class LevelManager;

    void lock() {
        LevelManager::Lock(*this);
    }

    void unlock() {
        LevelManager::Unlock(*this);
    }

private:
    size_t previous;
    Mutex mutex;
}; // class HierarchicalMutex

template <typename Mutex, size_t Level>
size_t level(HierarchicalMutex<Mutex,Level> const&) { return Level; }
```

The `LevelManager`'s role is simply to ensure that level transitions happen in correct order.

```
class LevelManager {
public:
    //
    // Single Mutex locking
    //
    template <typename M>
    static void Lock(M& m) {
        m.previous = LevelUp(level(m));
        m.mutex.lock();
    }

    template <typename M>
    static void Unlock(M& m) {
        m.mutex.unlock();
        LevelDown(level(m), m.previous);
    }

    //
    // Multiple Mutexes Group Locking
    //
    // Note: those should expose a "size_t level(M const&)" function,
    //       and calls to lock/unlock should appropriately call
    //       this manager to raise/lower the current level.
    //
    // Note: mutexes acquired as a group
    //       should be released with the same group.
    //
    template <typename M>
    static void Lock(std::array_ref<M*> mutexes) { // I wish this type existed
        using std::begin; using std::end;

        auto begin = begin(mutexes);
        auto end = end(mutexes);

        end = std::remove_if(begin, end, [](M const* m) { return m == 0; });

        if (begin == end) { return; }

        Sort(begin, end);

        size_t const previous = LevelUp(level(*std::prev(end)));

        for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
            begin->previous = previous;
            begin->mutex.lock();
        }
    }

    template <typename M>
    static void Unlock(std::array_ref<M*> mutexes) {
        using std::begin; using std::end;

        auto begin = begin(mutexes);
        auto end = end(mutexes);

        end = std::remove_if(begin, end, [](M const* m) { return m == 0; });

        if (begin == end) { return; }

        Sort(begin, end);

        std::reverse(begin, end);

        for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) { it->mutex.unlock(); }

        LevelDown(level(*begin), begin->previous);
    }

private:
    static __thread size_t CurrentLevel = 0;

    template <typename It>
    static void Sort(It begin, It end) {
        using Ref = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::const_reference;

        auto const sorter = [](Ref left, Ref right) {
            return std::tie(level(left), left) < std::tie(level(right), right);
        };

        std::sort(begin, end, sorter);
    }

    static size_t LevelUp(size_t const to) {
        if (CurrentLevel >= to) { throw LockHierarchyViolation(); }
        CurrentLevel = to;
    }

    static void LevelDown(size_t const from, size_t const to) {
        if (CurrentLevel != from) { throw LockHierarchyViolation(); }
        CurrentLevel = to;
    }
}; // class LevelManager
```

*For kicks, I implemented the possibility to lock multiples locks of the same level in a single shot.*

Comment: That looks really cool. Thanks for the response. I toyed with a [runtime checker](https://stacked-crooked.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Playground/LockOrderChecker/main.cpp) which detects inconsistent lock orderings, but never got to use it. It was a legacy project which I got permission to rewrite from scratch. I chose for a lock-free approach. Btw, it turns I indepently invented this passkey idiom you wrote about :) [I am experimenting with it for thread access control.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bbeb77f54234db6)

Answer (score 8):

No need for a separate class to manage the hierarchy. A nice solution can be found in *C++ Concurrency in Action*, by Anthony Williams ([ISBN 9781933988771](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action)):

```
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>

class hierarchical_mutex
{
    std::mutex internal_mutex;
    unsigned long const hierarchy_value;
    unsigned long previous_hierarchy_value;
    static thread_local unsigned long this_thread_hierarchy_value;

    void check_for_hierarchy_violation()
    {
        if(this_thread_hierarchy_value <= hierarchy_value)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("mutex hierarchy violated");
        }
    }
    void update_hierarchy_value()
    {
        previous_hierarchy_value=this_thread_hierarchy_value;
        this_thread_hierarchy_value=hierarchy_value;
    }
public:
    explicit hierarchical_mutex(unsigned long value):
        hierarchy_value(value),
        previous_hierarchy_value(0)
    {}
    void lock()
    {
        check_for_hierarchy_violation();
        internal_mutex.lock();
        update_hierarchy_value();
    }
    void unlock()
    {
        this_thread_hierarchy_value=previous_hierarchy_value;
        internal_mutex.unlock();
    }
    bool try_lock()
    {
        check_for_hierarchy_violation();
        if(!internal_mutex.try_lock())
            return false;
        update_hierarchy_value();
        return true;
    }
};
thread_local unsigned long
    hierarchical_mutex::this_thread_hierarchy_value(ULONG_MAX);       

int main()
{
    hierarchical_mutex m1(42);
    hierarchical_mutex m2(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you can do in this sort of case is just make sure your locks are always hierarchically applied (meaning nested). That way you can't access the level 3 lock without possessing the level 2 lock, which you can't access without first possessing the level 1 lock. You won't even be able to get to 3 without first getting to 1 and 2, so that should prevent major problems.

Can you be more specific in some of the deadlock cases that do arise? Maybe we can find a workaround for some of the particularly complicated things that may not be as easy to manipulate as I described above.